# Writing a NEST query to sort aggregation buckets by score

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-6

What I want is to create an aggregation bucket for each `unitId` (which is a field in my document). I want each bucket to be ordered by the max score in that bucket. I have written the following query which does what I want:

```
 "aggs": {
    "UnitAggregationBucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "unitId",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "max_score": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I am using script to find the max score per bucket, in a sub-aggregation. I don't know how to write the above query using NEST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Upadate:

This is the answer that  I got from [Elastic Community](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/writing-nested-aggregation-query-in-nest/179547):

> With 6.x, this would be something like:
>
> ```
> var client = new ElasticClient();
>
> var searchResponse = client.Search<object>(s => s
>     .Aggregations(a => a
>           .Terms("UnitAggregationBucket", t => t
>               .Field("unitId")
>           .Size(10)
>           .Order(o => o
>               .Descending("maximum_score")
>           )           
>             .Aggregations(aa => aa
>               .Max("maximum_score", m => m
>                   .Script("_score")
>               )
>           )
>       )
>   ) 
> );
>
> var termsAgg = searchResponse.Aggregations.Terms("UnitAggregationBucket");
>
> foreach(var bucket in termsAgg.Buckets)
> {     
>     // do something with buckets  
>     var maxScore = bucket.Max("maximum_score").Value; 
> }
> ```
>
> Note that you can't use max_score for the name of the aggregation as
>   it's a reserved keyword name in the client, which the client uses in
>   its heuristics based aggregation response JSON deserialization method.

---

### Original Answer

I managed to write the following NEST Query:

```
var unitAggregations = new TermsAggregation("UnitAggregationBucket")
{
    Size 10,
    Field = Field<MyDocument>(p => p.UnitId),
    Order = new List<TermsOrder>
    {
        new TermsOrder()
        {
            Key = "max_score_in_bucket",
            Order = SortOrder.Descending
        }
    },
    Aggregations = new MaxAggregation("max_score_in_bucket", string.Empty)
    {
        Script = new InlineScript("_score")
    }
};
```

Which produces, the following json:

```
"aggs": {
    "UnitAggregationBucket": {
      "aggs": {
        "max_score_in_bucket": {
          "max": {
            "script": {
              "source": "_score"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "terms": {
        "field": "unitId",
        "order": [
          {
            "max_score_in_bucket": "desc"
          }
        ],
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
```

It's not the exact json that I wanted, but it does what I want.

---

*Note: `max_score` is a reserved key-word in Elasticsearch, so I had to use a different name: `max_score_in_bucket`*